# Retornar dispositivos Bluetooth no Android

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

Olá,

Após muita pesquisa e estudo consegui finalizar uma classe que me retorna os dispositivos bluetooth pareados e ligados perto de um Android.
O problema que estou encontrando é na hora de atualizar minha `ListView` com os dispositivos que estão conectados. O pareado já deu certinho.

O problema é o seguinte, a lista que estou definindo no `setAdapter()` não possui o aparelho Bluetooth que conectei, por algum motivo essa lista é preenchida **depois** que o `setAdapter()` é executado e não consegui entender o porque disso.

**ListarBluetoothActivity.java**

```
package br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Forms;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.R;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID.Bluetooth;
import br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID.BluetoothListener;

public class ListarBluetoothActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothListener {
    private Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth(this);
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private List<BluetoothDevice> listaDispositivos = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listar_bluetooth);

        //region Bluetooth
        switch (bluetooth.verificarEstado()) {
            case LIGADO:
                bluetooth.iniciarBusca(this, this);

                listaDispositivos = bluetooth.getListaDispostivo();
                ListView lstBluetooth = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstBluetooth);
                BluetoothAdapter itemBluetooth = new BluetoothAdapter(this, listaDispositivos);

                lstBluetooth.setAdapter(itemBluetooth);
                break;
            case DESLIGADO:
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(bluetooth.getDispositivo().ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                break;
            case NAO_COMPATIVEL:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_bluetooth_nao_suportado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        //endregion

        //region Botão Procurar
        Button btnProcurar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProcurar_Bluetooth);
        btnProcurar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

            }
        });
        //endregion
    }

    //region Bluetooth
    @Override
    public void action(String action) {
        if (action.compareTo(ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED) == 0) {
            listaDispositivos = bluetooth.getListaDispostivo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    //Não habilitou Bluetooth, então fecha a tela.
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region Métodos não utilizados
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_listar_bluetooth, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    //endregion
}
```

**Bluetooth.java**

```
package br.ufscar.dc.controledepatrimonio.Util.RFID;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class Bluetooth extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private BluetoothListener listener;
    private BluetoothAdapter dispositivo;
    private List<BluetoothDevice> listaDispostivo = new ArrayList<>();

    public enum Estado {
        LIGADO, DESLIGADO, NAO_COMPATIVEL
    }

    public Bluetooth (BluetoothListener listener) {
        dispositivo = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        this.listener = listener;
        getDispositivosPareados();
    }

    public BluetoothAdapter getDispositivo() {
        return dispositivo;
    }

    public List<BluetoothDevice> getListaDispostivo(){
        return listaDispostivo;
    }

    //region getDispositivosPareados: Retorna todos dispositivos que já estão pareados com o aparelho
    private void getDispositivosPareados() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevicesList = dispositivo.getBondedDevices();

        if (pairedDevicesList.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevicesList) {
                listaDispostivo.add(device);
            }
        }
    }
    //endregion

    //region verificarEstado: Verifica se o recurso do Bluetooth está ativo
    public Estado verificarEstado() {
        if (dispositivo == null) {
            return Estado.NAO_COMPATIVEL;
        }
        if (!dispositivo.isEnabled()) {
            return Estado.DESLIGADO;
        }

        return Estado.LIGADO;
    }
    //endregion

    //region iniciarBusca: Inicia a busca de dispositivos que não estão pareados
    public void iniciarBusca(Context context, BluetoothListener listener) {
        Bluetooth bluetooth = new Bluetooth(listener);

        // Registro os Broadcast necessarios para a busca de dispositivos
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothListener.ACTION_FOUND);
        IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothListener.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothListener.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
        context.registerReceiver(bluetooth, filter);
        context.registerReceiver(bluetooth, filter2);
        context.registerReceiver(bluetooth, filter3);

        // inicio a busca e retorno a classe instanciada.
        dispositivo.startDiscovery();
    }
    //endregion

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        //caso encontre um dispositivo:
        if (action.compareTo(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND) == 0) {

            //pega as o dispositivo encontrado:
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

            //se a lista já tiver esse dispositivo eu retorno para o proximo
            //isso permite que sejá mostrado somente uma vez meu dispositivo
            //problema muito comum em exemplos
            if (listaDispostivo.contains(device)) {
                return;
            }

            //adiciono o dispositivo na minha lista:
            listaDispostivo.add(device);

        } else if (action.compareTo(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED) == 0) {
            //caso o discovery chegue ao fim eu desregistro meus broadcasts
            //SEMPRE FAÇA ISSO quando terminar de usar um broadcast
            context.unregisterReceiver(this);
        }

        if (listener != null) {
            //se foi definido o listener eu aviso a quem ta gerenciando.
            listener.action(action);
        }
    }
}
```

Eu coloco o break-point na linha `listaDispostivo.add(device)` da classe Bluetooth e ele está passando por lá normalmente. Inclusive preenchendo a lista com o valor esperado. O erro é que isso não é informado na lista do `setAdapter()`.

Se alguém puder me dar uma luz de onde estou errando eu agradeço :)

Answer (score 1):

Após preencher o List  `lstBluetooth` você deve chamar o evento `notifyDataSetChanged();` do seu Adapter da seguinte forma:

```
itemBluetooth.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Assim ele atualiza seu ListView